# What are valid SQL functions for OLEDB provider for querying a text file?

Tags: .net, sql, oledb

Does anyone know of any documentation out there that lays out what SQL functions are supported for the .NET Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0 provider when querying a text file?

For instance, the TRIM() function. However, there doesn't appear to be a CASE function like in SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of any such reference. But see if using IIF helps.